# Solving an Equation Without the Implicit Function Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For a homework assignment: how can I figure out where I can solve the equation $F(x,y) = y^2 + y + 3x + 1 = 0$ for $y$ *without* using the implicit function theorem?  My initial feeling is that we could treat $(3x + 1)$ as the $c$ term of a quadratic function, and solve for the legal values of x using the following:
\begin{align}
b^2 - 4ac &\ge 0 \\
1 - 4(3x + 1) &\ge 0 \\
3x + 1 & \le \frac{1}{4} \\
x &\le \frac{5}{12}
\end{align}
but the back of my textbook says the answer is $x \le -\frac{1}{4}$.  Did I do something wrong, or is my book at fault?

Comment: Hint: if $x$ were constant could you solve this equation for $y$?

Comment: You mean you are solving for $y$ in terms of $x$? (I think this is an algebra problem and not a calculus problem.) Notice that the equation is quadratic in $y$. So it is like something of the form $ay^2+by+c=0$. In this case, $c=3x+1$ (as strange as it looks), and use the quadratic formula to complete the solution.

Comment: See the updated version of my question.  And yes, this is probably more of an algebra question, but I wanted to make it clear that this is a calc problem where the implicit function theorem is not allowed.

Comment: Never mind, I'm an idiot.  I added 1 instead of subtracting 1.

Comment: If you are an idiot, then I guess all of us here are idiots many times over. Don't be so hard on yourself. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use quadratic formula: $y^2+y + 3x+1  = 0 \to y = \dfrac{-1\pm \sqrt{1^2-4(3x+1)}}{2}=\dfrac{-1\pm \sqrt{-12x-3}}{2}$. From this you see that in order for you to have a $y$ then $\triangle \geq 0 \to -12x-3 \geq 0 \to x \leq -\dfrac{1}{4}$